Can't call POOL.flashLoan provided by Aave
I'm trying to call POOL.flashLoan provided by Aave core v3. This is for a test and done on forked mainnet using ganache/truffle.
contract FlashLoanArbitrage {

    IPool public POOL;
    
    constructor(
        address _poolAddressesProvider,
    )
    {
        IPoolAddressesProvider provider = IPoolAddressesProvider(_poolAddressesProvider);
        POOL = IPool(provider.getPool());  // Initialize the POOL contract
    }

    function executeFlashLoan(
        address[] calldata assets,
        uint256[] calldata flashLoanAmounts,
        uint256[] calldata modes,
        address onBehalfOf,
        bytes calldata params
    ) external {

        POOL.flashLoan(address(this), assets, flashLoanAmounts, modes, onBehalfOf, params, 0);
    }

}


In above Solidity code, as recommended in the official Aave documentation, I am using poolAddressProvider contract to obtain the address of the POOL contract. Then calling executeFlashLoan, which is my endpoint, shuold run POOL.flashloan to request the loan. However, callng this endpoint failes due to flashLoan not properly being called.
Since truffle debug did not provide much information to indicate what went wrong, I tried to directly call flashLoan via web3 python, which did not work either.
   pool_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=pool_address, abi=pool_abi)

    # Proceed with your existing code using POOL_contract
    address = '0xb9af6288810670DAb8bb01CB51A37Af334A90304'
    assets = ["0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2"]
    amounts = [Web3.to_wei(100, 'ether')]
    modes = [0]
    on_behalf_of = address
    params = b""

    logger.info(f'{address=}')
    logger.info(f'{assets=}')
    logger.info(f'{amounts=}')
    logger.info(f'{modes=}')
    logger.info(f'{on_behalf_of=}')
    logger.info(f'{params=}')

    try:
        result = pool_contract.functions.flashLoan(
            address,
            assets,
            amounts,
            modes,
            on_behalf_of,
            params,
            0
        ).call({'from': address})
        logger.info("Flash loan simulation successful. Result:", result)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Flash loan simulation error: %s", e)


2024-10-27 12:13:09 [INFO] address='0xb9af6288810670DAb8bb01CB51A37Af334A90304'
2024-10-27 12:13:09 [INFO] assets=['0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2']
2024-10-27 12:13:09 [INFO] amounts=[100000000000000000000]
2024-10-27 12:13:09 [INFO] modes=[0]
2024-10-27 12:13:09 [INFO] on_behalf_of='0xb9af6288810670DAb8bb01CB51A37Af334A90304'
2024-10-27 12:13:09 [INFO] params=b'' 
2024-10-27 12:14:15 [ERROR] Flash loan simulation error: ("The function 'flashLoan' was not found in this contract's abi.", ' Are you sure you provided the correct contract abi?')

Since the erorr suggests that contract abi (or its address) is not accurate, I checked the following:

I'm passing the '0x2f39d218133AFaB8F2B819B1066c7E434Ad94E9e' to instanciate 'IPoolAddressesProvider,and it can be confirmed that this indeed belongs to the contract 'PoolAddressesProvider'

The address given to IPOOL to instantiate POOL contract is '0x87870Bca3F3fD6335C3F4ce8392D69350B4fA4E2', and it can be confirmed that this belongs to 'InitializableImmutableAdminUpgradeabilityProxy'

On etherscan,at contract tab, 'InitializableImmutableAdminUpgradeabilityProxy' includes the flashLoan implementation in POOL.sol (this can be confirmed by looking into IDE)



function flashLoan(
    address receiverAddress,
    address[] calldata assets,
    uint256[] calldata amounts,
    uint256[] calldata interestRateModes,
    address onBehalfOf,
    bytes calldata params,
    uint16 referralCode
  ) public virtual override {
    DataTypes.FlashloanParams memory flashParams = DataTypes.FlashloanParams({
      receiverAddress: receiverAddress,
      assets: assets,
      amounts: amounts,
      interestRateModes: interestRateModes,
      onBehalfOf: onBehalfOf,
      params: params,
      referralCode: referralCode,
      flashLoanPremiumToProtocol: _flashLoanPremiumToProtocol,
      flashLoanPremiumTotal: _flashLoanPremiumTotal,
      reservesCount: _reservesCount,
      addressesProvider: address(ADDRESSES_PROVIDER),
      pool: address(this),
      userEModeCategory: _usersEModeCategory[onBehalfOf],
      isAuthorizedFlashBorrower: IACLManager(ADDRESSES_PROVIDER.getACLManager()).isFlashBorrower(
        msg.sender
      )
    });
 

I suspect that I might not be passing the parameters in the expected format, or not instanciating the POOL contract right, etc. Could anybody help me resolve this?

Where did you get the ABI from? If from Etherscan, it's probably just the ABI of the proxy contract, and not of the implementation itself. That might be why you're getting the message that flashloan is not available as per the contract's ABI. You need to get the ABI of the implementation contract. Looks like the proxy contract has an implementation function which returns the current impl's address. Then you can get the ABI from there. Or maybe from AAVE itself somewhere.

Thanks, and you're right. I now tried
pool_address = proxy_contract.functions.implementation().call()
which failed with the error message:
'message': 'VM Exception while processing transaction: revert'
'stack': 'CallError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
I'm wondering if this has to do with the fact that I'm running this on forked mainnet (ganache)?
As for abi, I think I found it here, which inclues a signature for flashLoan. I just need the address....
